# How to read Google's GWT request body with NodeJS's bodyparser into string variable?

Tags: node.js, express, gwt, body-parser

I've already tried every possible method with almost all possible option from this documentation:
https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser

I've tried to read the request body with:

```
app.use(bodyParser.text());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.raw());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

I've tried some options too, but every version returned an Object (which I can't cast to String), instead of the String.

Is it possible to read the body of this request type somehow?

```
Content-Type: text/x-gwt-rpc; charset=UTF-8
```

Thanks for your help!